# Error MSB3721 when trying to assemble a simple subtraction program in assembly

Tags: assembly, visual-studio-2013, masm, irvine32

I am writing a simple assembly program which has to subtract 3 integers, using only 16 bit registers. Then I have to call DumpRegs to show the output.

I am using Microsoft Visual Studio 2013.

My code:

```
INCLUDE Irvine32.inc    

.386                    

.model flat, stdcall    

.stack 4096             

ExitProcess PROTO, dwExitCode:DWORD

.data                   
    integerOne WORD 10  ; 16 bit WORD integerOne with the value 10
    integerTwo WORD 3   ; 16 bit WORD integerTwo with the value 3
    integerThree WORD 5 ; 16 bit WORD integerThree with the value 5
    finalAnswer WORD ?  ; 16 bit WORD finalAnswer with a unknown value
                        ; to store the subtraction answer

.code   ; Start of the code section
main PROC   ; Main Procedure Start

    mov EAX, 0          ; Moves 0 into the EAX register

    mov AX, integerOne  ; Loads the AX register with integerOne (10)

    sub AX, integerTwo  ; Subtracts integerTwo (3) from the AX register

    sub AX, integerThree    ; Subtracts integerThree (5) from the AX register

    mov finalAnswer, AX ; Moves the contents of the AX register into finalAnswer

    call DumpRegs       ; Outputs the registers

    INVOKE ExitProcess,0    

main ENDP

END main
```

The error I am getting when I am starting without Debugging is the following:

```
Error   2   error MSB3721: The command "ml.exe /c /nologo /Zi /Fo"Debug\Subtracting Three Integers.obj" /W3 /errorReport:prompt  /Ta"Subtracting Three Integers.asm"" exited with code 1.   C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V120\BuildCustomizations\masm.targets 50  5   CSE 210 Assignment 2
```

I also get a warning:

```
Warning 1   warning A4011: multiple .MODEL directives found : .MODEL i  C:\Users\Tapan\Desktop\Desktop Files\VS\CSE 210 Assignment 2\Subtracting Three Integers.asm 14  1   CSE 210 Assignment 2
```

This program ran fine yesterday, here is the output window screenshot:

[image: Output Window]

Comment: If you include `INCLUDE Irvine32.inc` I believe it automatically sets `.386`, `.stack 4096`, and `.model flat, stdcall` for you. I think part of your problem is that you are redefining these things. Try removing all three of those lines, but keep the  `INCLUDE Irvine32.inc`

Comment: @MichaelPetch I commented the .386, .stack 4096, and the .model flat, stdcall, and it worked! Thanks a bunch!

Comment: *I commented them out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using Kip's Irvine Win32 library and you do this:

```
INCLUDE Irvine32.inc
```

You are implicitly doing this under the hood:

```
.386                    
.model flat, stdcall    
.stack 4096
```

By doing `include irvine32.inc` AND doing the above 3 lines you are defining these options twice. The Microsoft Assembler sees this as an error. This was suggested in this somewhat cryptic error message where it complained about multiple `.model` directives being defined:

```
warning A4011: multiple .MODEL directives found : .MODEL i C:\Users\Tapan\Desktop\Desktop Files\VS\CSE 210 Assignment 2\Subtracting Three Integers.asm 14  1   CSE 210 Assignment 2
```

I believe that to avoid this problem when using `include irvine32.inc` you simply remove all three of the following lines and just include *irvine32.inc*:

```
.386                    
.model flat, stdcall    
.stack 4096  ; If a bigger stack is needed(>4096) then define it to be larger
```